# How to call a member functions from within a mouse handler?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, event-handling

Let say I've a class such as:

```
class IWavePlayer : public IControl
{
private:
    WDL_String mWavePath;

public:
    IWavePlayer() { 
        // some task
    }

    void LoadWave() {
        mWavePath = PromptForFile();
        // some task with mWavePath
    }
};
```

which I instance it in the main with `IWavePlayer pWavePlayer;`.

Now, I need to call (within another control that "handle" a mouse click) the function `LoadWave()` of `pWavePlayer`:

```
class ICustomButton : public IControl
{
private:


public:
    ICustomButton()  {
        // some task
    }

    void ICustomButton::OnMouseDown(int x, int y, IMouseMod *pMod) {
        pWavePlayer.LoadWave();
    }
};
```

I can't call here `pWavePlayer.LoadWave();`, because obviously it doesn't "know" `pWavePlayer`. And I can't pass to the ICustomButton the instance of `pWavePlayer` (since it will be specific for just 1 button, for example).

How would you usually manage this situation? What's the correct pattern for doing this?

Comment: Well, what if there's more than one WavePlayer? Which one do you want to load the wave?

Comment: We also don't know what `pWavePlayer` is.

Comment: I have only 1 WavePlayer. If I have another one, it's another instance. As I said, I need to call `pWavePlayer.LoadWave();`, which is Unique!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to call a member-function on an object from an unrelated member function of another object, you need to provide the caller with a reference or a pointer to the target. This is typically done in the constructor:

```
class ICustomButton : public IControl {
private:
    IWavePlayer *pWavePlayer;
public:
    ICustomButton(IWavePlayer *wp) : pWavePlayer(wp)  {
        // some task
    }
    void ICustomButton::OnMouseDown(int x, int y, IMouseMod *pMod) {
        pWavePlayer->LoadWave();
    }
};
```

This can also be done by providing some sort of a "locator service" or a "registry" through which a pointer to `IWavePlayer` can be found without providing any references at all. For example, if there is only one `IWavePlayer` in the system, it could be made a singleton, meaning that it is accessible throughout the system as `IWavePlayer::instance`.

If you do not want to have a reference to `IWavePlayer` in your `ICustomButton` at all, you could use `std::function` to add another layer of abstraction:

```
class ICustomButton : public IControl {
private:
    std::function<void(void)> action;
public:
    ICustomButton(std::function& f) : action(f)  {
        // some task
    }
    void ICustomButton::OnMouseDown(int x, int y, IMouseMod *pMod) {
        action();
    }
};
```

Now the caller who creates the button can provide an action as `std::function<void(void)>`, which could embed a reference to `pWavePlayer` in it.

Here is a complete example illustrating the approach:

```
class Button {
    function<void(void)> action;
public:
    Button(function<void(void)> f) : action(f) {}
    void click() {
        action();
    }
};

class WavePlayer {
public:
    void load() {
        cout << "loaded" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    WavePlayer player;
    Button b([&] {
        player.load();
    });
    b.click();
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/d1EnQD)

Comment: As I said, that's could be a problem. Because maybe this button need `IWavePlayer *pWavePlayer`. Another button on click needs another Object, and so on. I can't "add" for every future target, all what I need.

Comment: @paizza This means that your `ICustomButton::OnMouseDown` must not have references to `LoadWave` member function at all. In this case adding another level of indirection may be warranted (see edit).

Comment: Can you give to me an example on how you would create a new ICustomButton that will handle a function within the place where I create it?  Not sure if I got it...

Comment: on `std::function& f` within the CTOR it says argument list for class std::function is missing.

Comment: @paizza I edited to add an example and a running demo.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem for an [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

In C++ you can easily implement this with a template. You can use one I wrote for an OSS project. You can extract it from this [observer.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/datinator/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/support_lib/support/patterns/observer.h)

Basically what you do is, you declare your mouse handler object as a `Dispatcher`, and whatever object wants to receive it as the `Listener`. In your mouse handler, you call the notify method, and then all observers (or listeners) will be notified with your event. The advantage of this approach is, that there is no dependency between the two objects, so you can easily add different objects which may also be interested in this event without changing the objects themselve.

Here is a simple demo (compiled with VS2015 but should also work on gcc as this is where I developed it originally).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename... T> class Dispatcher;
template <typename... T> class Listener;

#define ListenerList        std::vector
#define UNUSED(x) (x)

template <typename... T>
class Listener
{
public:
    Listener(void)
    {
    }

    virtual ~Listener(void)
    {
    }

    virtual void handleNotification(Dispatcher<T...> *oSource, T... /* oEvent */)
    {
        // Default implementation does nothing
        // which can be used as a null listener where
        // a listener is expected but doesn't have
        // a meaningful implementation.
        UNUSED(oSource);
    }

    /**
    * The invalidateDispatcher() call is sent when the dispatcher
    * should no longer be accessed anymore. After this call, the listener
    * will no longer receive any notifications and the dispatcher is
    * destroyed, so the listener should not unregister with
    * removeListener().
    */
    virtual void invalidateDispatcher(Dispatcher<T...> const *oDispatcher)
    {
        UNUSED(oDispatcher);
    }
};

template <typename... T>
class Dispatcher
{
public:
    Dispatcher(void)
    {
        mAllowDuplicates = false;
    }

    virtual ~Dispatcher(void)
    {
        invalidate();
    }

    void allowDuplicates(bool bAllowDuplicates = true)
    {
        mAllowDuplicates = bAllowDuplicates;
    }

    /**
    * After the invalidate() message is sent to the listeners,
    * they will no longer receive any notifications and they should
    * no longer access the dispatcher pointer as the object became invalid.
    * When this call is sent, the listener also shouldn't
    * unregister via removeListener().
    */
    virtual void invalidate(void)
    {
        for (Listener<T...> * &listener : mListeners)
            listener->invalidateDispatcher(this);
    }

    virtual void notify(T... oEvent)
    {
        for (Listener<T...> * &listener : mListeners)
            listener->handleNotification(this, oEvent...);
    }

    /**
    * Adds a listener to the dispatcher. A listener
    * can attach itself multiple times, in which case
    * it will receive as many notifications as it
    * is registered. When the listener is removed
    * it will remove all instances with a single call
    * so there is no need to balance the addListener()
    * with removeListener() calls.
    */
    virtual void addListener(Listener<T...> *oListener)
    {
        if (!mAllowDuplicates)
        {
            if (listenerIndex(oListener) != -1)
                return;
        }

        mListeners.push_back(oListener);
    }

    virtual void removeListener(Listener<T...> *oListener)
    {
        // The listener may have registered multiple times
        // so we must remove all instances.
        int i;
        while ((i = listenerIndex(oListener)) != -1)
            mListeners.erase(mListeners.begin() + i);
    }

protected:
    ListenerList<Listener<T...> *> &getListeners(void) const
    {
        return mListeners;
    }

    virtual int listenerIndex(Listener<T...> const *oListener) const
    {
        int i = -1;
        for (Listener<T...> * const &listener : mListeners)
        {
            i++;
            if (listener == oListener)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

private:
    ListenerList<Listener<T...> *> mListeners;
    bool mAllowDuplicates;
};


class Mousehandler : public Dispatcher<bool /* ButtonState */, int /* x Position */, int /* y Position */>
{
public:
    Mousehandler(void) {}

    void buttonePressed(int nButtonState, int x, int y)
    {
        if (nButtonState == 1)      // Button up
            notify(true, x, y);
        else
            notify(false, x, y);        // Button down.
    }
};


class MouseListener : public Listener<bool, int, int>
{
public:
    MouseListener(int id) { mId = id;  }

    void handleNotification(Dispatcher<bool, int, int> *oSource, bool bButtonPress, int nX, int nY) override
    {
        UNUSED(oSource);

        if (bButtonPress)
            std::cout << mId << ": Button was pressed at " << nX << "/" << nY << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << mId << ": Button was released at " << nX << "/" << nY << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int mId;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    Mousehandler h;
    MouseListener l1(1);
    MouseListener l2(2);

    h.addListener(&l1);
    h.addListener(&l2);

    h.buttonePressed(true, 10, 15);
    h.buttonePressed(false, 20, 11);

    return 0;
}
```

If you are using an older compiler you may not have variadic arguments, in which case you have to change the template to accept only one typename, and you have to use a pointer to a struct or class, if you need to send more than one parameter as your event. With C++11 it's easier and IMO clearer.

This is the same but using mulitple events on the handler.

```
class Mousehandler
    : public Dispatcher<bool /* ButtonState */, int /* x Position */, int /* y Position */>
    , public Dispatcher<int /* x Position */, int /* y Position */>
{
public:
    typedef Dispatcher<bool, int , int > button_handler;
    typedef Dispatcher<int, int > move_handler;
    typedef Listener<bool, int, int > button_listener;
    typedef Listener<int, int > move_listener;

public:
    Mousehandler(void) {}

    void buttonPressed(int nButtonState, int x, int y)
    {
        if (nButtonState == 1)      // Button up
            Dispatcher<bool, int, int>::notify(true, x, y);
        else
            Dispatcher<bool, int, int>::notify(false, x, y);        // Button down.
    }

    void mouseMoved(int x, int y)
    {
        Dispatcher<int, int >::notify(x, y);
    }

    void addButtonListener(button_listener *pListener)
    {
        button_handler::addListener(pListener);
    }

    void addMoveListener(move_listener *pListener)
    {
        move_handler::addListener(pListener);
    }
};


class MouseListener 
    : public Listener<bool, int, int>
    , public Listener<int, int>
{
public:
    MouseListener(int id) { mId = id;  }

    void handleNotification(Mousehandler::button_handler *oSource, bool bButtonPress, int nX, int nY) override
    {
        UNUSED(oSource);

        if (bButtonPress)
            std::cout << mId << ": Button was pressed at " << nX << "/" << nY << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << mId << ": Button was released at " << nX << "/" << nY << std::endl;
    }

    void handleNotification(Mousehandler::move_handler *oSource, int nX, int nY) override
    {
        UNUSED(oSource);

        std::cout << mId << ": Mouse moved to " << nX << "/" << nY << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int mId;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    Mousehandler h;
    MouseListener l1(1);
    MouseListener l2(2);

    h.addButtonListener(&l1);
    h.addMoveListener(&l1);

    // No need for movements on the second listener.
    h.addButtonListener(&l2);

    h.buttonPressed(true, 10, 15);
    h.buttonPressed(false, 20, 11);

    h.mouseMoved(12, 20);
    h.mouseMoved(21, 23);

    return 0;
}
```